# Iterate controls in a Windows form, Visual C++/CLI

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I am new to Visual C++/CLI.
I have several controls in a form, including a  tabstrip. I can iterate them by:

```
for each(Control^ ctrl in this->Controls){
       // bla bla bla
}
```

But `this->Controls->Count` won't return the controls inside the tabstrip. I, of course, can check them by `tabStrip->Controls->Count;`

Can anybody explain me why ?

Thanks

Comment: It is logically arranged as a *tree*.  Your loop only iterates the controls that have the form as their Parent, not the controls that are nested inside other containers.  Like that "tabstrip", whatever that might be.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Now, is there a way to iterate through all controls within a form ? ... or iterate through all the containers ?

Comment: Check your favorite data structures book.  The best way to visit every node in a tree is with a recursive method.